# Multiple VkDescriptorSetLayout for the same VkPipeline?

Tags: c++, vulkan

I have two Entities to be rendered with the same `VkPipeline`, the problem is that they have different `VkDescriptorSetLayout` (The first entities uses Dynamic Uniform Buffers, the second only standard Uniform Buffers);

How to pass both `VkDescriptorSetLayout` to the graphics pipeline, and then bind the correct one during the creation of the command buffer?

With a single `VkDescriptorSetLayout`, I just pass it to `VkPipelineLayoutCreateInfo.pSetLayouts`, and then call `VkCmdBindDescriptorSet` with that `VkPipelineLayout`.

But with two `VkDescriptorSetLayouts`, how to correctly bind them to the `VkPipelineLayout`, and then how to choose the one I want during command buffering?

Comment: Make two Pipelines, and then bind the one you need?

Comment: Yes, I think there are two solutions: A unique pipeline that only uses dynamic uniform buffers (Like Nicol Bolas said), or two different pipelines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The first entities uses Dynamic Uniform Buffers, the second only standard Uniform Buffers

Then they do not have the same `VkPipeline`. Whether a uniform buffer is dynamic or not is *part of the pipeline*, since it is part of the layout of that pipeline's descriptor sets.

Pipelines can have multiple descriptor sets, but each set represents a collection of resources, *all of which* the pipeline can access at the same time. In your shader code, this is what `layout(set = #, binding = #)` means; a uniform block in the shader refers to a specific descriptor within a *specific set index*. And it will always refer to that specific descriptor within that specific set index. And whether that specific descriptor within that specific set is dynamic or not is a part of the `VkDescritorSetLayout` used by the `VkPipelineLayout` used to construct the `VkPipeline` object.

A specific descriptor set within a pipeline layout cannot have two sets. That doesn't make sense.

To do what you want requires creating two separate, distinct `VkPipeline` objects. One can be a derivative of the other, so as to hint to the implementation that changes between them won't be particularly big. But you need two pipelines.

But really, it'd probably be better to just have one pipeline that always using dynamic uniform buffers.

Comment: Can you please explain why it is possible to bind multiple VkDescriptorSetLayout to the same VkPipelineLayout then?

Comment: @ShockCoding: It's the paragraph that starts with "Pipelines can have multiple descriptor sets". The sets are not *alternative* resources; they're a *list* of resources. It's also why you specify a set index in your shader for the resources.

Comment: I popped here by doing research, and when you said layout(set=#,descriptor=#), "descriptor" should'nt be "binding" instead ?